# Permission Denied Reading Mounted Volume from within Docker Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, airflow, file-permissions

I have a container `webserver` started using Docker Compose which also mounts the host volume `/data/foo` to the `/data/foo` in the container. On the host, this directory has the permissions `754` and is owned by user `foo` and group `friends`. My current user on the host is `bar` and belong to the group `friends` too.

**Problem:** After I attach to the container's `bash` shell, I am unable to access `/data/foo` due to insufficient permissions:

```
# Inside docker container..

$ ls /data/foo
ls: cannot access '/data/foo': Permission denied

$ ls -l /data
drwxr-xr-- 9 1004 1004 4096 May 10 12:34 foo
```

On the host, I have no problem accessing the contents as user `bar`:

```
# Outside on the host...

$ ls -l /data
total 12
drwxrwxr-- 7 foo friends 4096 May 10 12:34 foo

$ ls -l /data/foo
total 24
drwxrwxr-- 7 foo friends 4096 May 10 12:34 hello
```

Even changing the permissions to `777` on the host for these directories does not provide access to them from inside the Docker container.

However, if I were to change the owner of the directories from `foo` to `1000` on the host, I will finally be able to access the files from within the Docker container.

Is there anyway we can access `/data/foo` from inside the Docker container without changing the directory/file ownerships on the host?

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        ...

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - /data/foo:/data/foo
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, on linux, the volume keep it's uid/gid from the host when mounted in a container. You need to fix the uid/gid of the user inside the container when the container start. You can check the issue with some solutions here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22258#issuecomment-247059898